# Boost async_read reads zero bytes from pipe

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to asynchrosouly read from a pipe using boost::asio::async_read, but it reads zero bytes everytime.
However, I can succussfuly read from the pipe using the read function(unistd.h);

here's my code:

```
    auto io = make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>();
    auto work = make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(*io);
    int read_end = atoi(argv[0]);
    auto pipe_read = make_shared<boost::asio::readable_pipe>(*io, read_end);
    string message;

    boost::thread_group worker_threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        // I'm calling io->run() inside the worker thread.
        worker_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&workerThread, io));
    }

    // The handler function gets the number of bytes read, which is always zero.
    boost::asio::async_read(*pipe_read, boost::asio::buffer(message, 5), boost::bind(&handler, _1, _2));
    cout << message << endl;

    work.reset();
    worker_threads.join_all();
    return 0;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `argv[0]` is a bug. Also, printing `message` before joining the execution context is a bug and a data race

Comment: I'm running the program from inside another program using execl, that's why I'm using argv[0], although I'm not sure if using exec functions works the same way on different operating systems. I'll fix the race condition, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a

```
std::string message;
```

then `asio::buffer(message)` has size 0 (because the string is empty).

The overload taking a size `asio::buffer(message, 5)` can only *limit* the size, but doesn't provide it. So it is still size 0.

This explains your symptoms. Instead,

```
std::string message(5, '\0');
auto b = asio::buffer(message);
```

Or, alternatively,

```
std::string message;
message.resize(1024); // cue Bill Gates miss-quote
auto b = asio::buffer(message, 5);
```

Or even use dynamic buffers:

```
std::string message;
auto b = asio::dynamic_buffer(message/*, 5*/);
```

### Live Demo

Showing a modernized version also fixing the various bugs I remarked:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/385b36b499748ed0)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

void handler(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t xfr) {
    std::cout << "Received " << xfr << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::thread_pool ioc(1); // or more threads
    assert(argc > 1);
    int  read_end  = atoi(argv[1]);
    auto pipe_read = make_shared<boost::asio::readable_pipe>(ioc, read_end);

    std::string message(5, '\0');
    boost::asio::async_read(*pipe_read, asio::buffer(message), &handler);

    ioc.join();
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
./a.out 0 <<< "HELLO WORLD"
Received 5 bytes (Success)
HELLO
```